# Modifying the eclipse code and creating feature patch

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am building an eclipse rcp application. For the Drag and Drop functionality of resources I need extraset of validations. Eclipse doesn't suggest to subclass the ResourceDropAdapterAssistant. So I modified the code for ResourceDropAdapterAssistant which is in the package org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.

Now what is the best way to put this feature back to my eclipse? I have gone through this link. http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/30/patching-your-own-eclipse-ide/

It has helped me to create a feature patch. But I am clear when I create the feature patch should I include only the modified class or all classes and packages under the plug-in?

Regards,
Priyank Thakkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should to only copy the .class files for the modified java files.  However, I have created several feature patches and just find it easier and less error prone to include all .class files.  So, that is what I would recommend doing.

Remember though that by default, a feature patch applies to exactly one version of the released feature.  However, you can modify the created p2 metadata to expand the range.  See these excellent blog posts for more information:

http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2009/06/patching-features-with-p2.html

http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2009/06/patching-features-part-2.html